# Counting how many times multiple different text strings exist in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been struggling to count how many times multiple different text strings appear in a cell.

In column `A`, I have a text string with multiple file types, and I'm trying to count how many of each file type occur in that string.

Does any formula count the number of times a text string occurs in a single cell?

**Expected Result**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Apparently you have two Super User accounts: [NBG](//superuser.com/users/936629) and [NBSG SG](//superuser.com/users/936630). This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer. Please take the time to utilise [this Help Center tutorial](//superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) and ask the Stack Exchange staff to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 2):

> Does any formula count the number of times a text string occurs in a single cell?

Not directly, but you can calculate it:

`=(LEN(A1) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"doc",""))) / LEN("doc")`

---

### Update

To change the formula to look for entire words only would make it very complicated with standard Excel formulas.

Here I use free [Regex Find/Replace](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) add-in.

With that you can use this formula:

`=(LEN(A1)-LEN(RegExReplace(A1,"(\W?)doc(?!\w)","$1")))/LEN("doc")`

How it works:

- `(?!\w)` is a negative lookahead, considers only `doc` when it's not followed by that letter
- `(\W?)` - as this add-in doesn't support lookbehind, here I use a group construct, looking for a non-letter before `doc`

*(note: I like that add-in and not affiliated with it in any way)*

Comment: I don't have enough reputation score to reply @Máté Juhász. According to your answer, the formula will calculate the word "document" also. If I paste the formula =(LEN(A2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"doc",""))) / LEN("doc") So the column B the result will become **2** instead of **1**. Thank you for your comment but not a good formula to solve my question.

Comment: @NBSGSG please see my update

Answer (score 1):

For your specific situation, a formula solution is relatively simple.

Enter the following formula in `B2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down/auto-fill into the rest of the table's column:

```dart
=(LEN($A2&",")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2&",","/doc,","")))/LEN("/doc,")
```

Repeat this formula for the other columns, changing the `doc` to the column's file type. However, for the `no. of text` column, you need to use `plain` instead on `text`.

**Explanation:**

Adding a comma to the end of the string in column `A` guarantees that the sub-string we are looking for is always delimited with a `/` prefix and a `,` suffix.

The count of the sub-string occurrences is then simply the difference between the length of the full string, and the full string with the delimited sub-strings removed, divided by the length of the delimited sub-string.

---

A slightly more complicated formula can also be constructed that extracts the file-type to be counted from the header itself, thus only requiring a single formula for the entire table:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `B2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down&right/auto-fill into the rest of the table:

```dart
=(LEN($A2)+1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2&",","/"&MID(B$1,8,LEN(B$1))&",","")))/(LEN(MID(B$1,8,LEN(B$1)))+2)
```

Note that the header for column `H` has to be change to `no. of plain` for this formula to work as per your requirements.

**Explanation:**

This formula works in essentially the same way as the previous one.

The only major difference is that instead of hard-coding the file type, `MID(B$1,8,LEN(B$1))` is used to extract it from the header. This is essentially the equivalent of a two-argument only `MID()` function that extracts the sub-string from the 8th character to the end of the string. (`LEN(B$1)` is used instead of an arbitrarily large number as it results in the "cleanest" no-chance-of-a-bug solution.)

The other, minor difference in this formula is a slight simplification achieved by hard-coding the lengths of the delimiters.